# How to find the hermitian adjoint and inverse of an operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a translation operator defined as:

$$
\hat{T_a}\Psi(x)=\Psi(x+a) \, .
$$

Now, how do I find the hermitian adjoint operator as well as its inverse?

Comment: what have you tried? The inverse should be really easy, what is an inverse supposed to do? For the adjoint, try to write down the definition of adjoint (in terms of inner products) and applying it to this operator

Comment: Considered $\hat T_a = e^{a\partial_x}$? What do you get by expanding in *a* and integrating by parts every terms so all derivatives act on the left?